# I have to click the back button twice to go back to the previous activity

Tags: android, android-studio, back-button, back

I created an activity that contains `search view` and `list view`.
When I'm trying to go back to the `main activity` I have to press back `button` two times , first one the pointer on the `search view` disappear ,the second take me to the `main activity`.

how to solve that ?
I need to go directly to the `main activity` when pressing back `button`.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drugs);

    lv= findViewById(R.id.idlistview);
    searchView= findViewById(R.id.idsearch);

    drugadapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    lv.setAdapter(drugadapter);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    View focused = getCurrentFocus();
    focused.clearFocus();

     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
      {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, 
       long id) {


        Intent intent2=new 
        Intent(DrugsActivity.this,ResultDrugActivity.class);
        intent2.putExtra("drug",lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
        intent2.putExtra("age", age11 );
        intent2.putExtra("weight", weight11 );
        startActivity(intent2);
    }
     });


        boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
       drugadapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
          return false;
           }
```

Comment: Where is your **`CODE`** without **`CODE`** how we can help you?

Comment: Especially any code in `onBackPressed()` in case you override it.

Comment: Please post your activity code and scenario screen-shot here so we can check it.

Comment: @NileshRathod the code added

Comment: @ChintakPatel The code added

Answer (score 0):

**By reading your scenario hope this will help you and if not post your code**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    hideKeyboard();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**So when the onBackPressed() is called within our layout we then can do whatever we want like hide the keyboard:**

```
private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mInputField.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(lv.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
      lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this way just hides list view and make press one more time on back button'